# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
 <?php

include ("apps/controller/database.php"); include ("header.php");
//Connect to the DB $database->connect(); //Check the url has been set
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {


$url = isset($_POST['url']) ? $database->escape($_POST['url']) : false;
//$url = isset($_POST['url']) ? $database->escape($_POST['url']) : '';
//This is optional ;)
$password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $database->escape($_POST['password']) : '';
//Okay, now we've figured out if they've set the url, let's add it to the DB
if (isset($url)) {
    $id = md5(uniqid());
    $res = $database->query("INSERT INTO urls (url,pass,key) VALUES('".$url."','".$password."','".$id."')");
    echo '<br /><br /><div id="both" class="types both"><a href="http://localhost/view.php?id=' .
        $id . '">http://localhost/view.php?id=' . $id . '</a></div>';
}
//Close the DB
$database->close();
}else
{
    echo '<br /><br /><div id="err" class="notification error"><a class="close" href="#" alt="close" title="Close this notification"> </a> You cannot view this URL directly. Please create a url.</div>';
}


$database->close();
```

My MYSQL structure is: id, url, views, keys

Comment: I highly recommend separating the functionality between your presentation and your database connectivity.

Comment: You're better off using an auto increment primary key. It avoids the overhead of having to create an id every time you insert a row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`key` is a [MySQL reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), you need to quote it with backticks if you want to use it as a field name.

```
INSERT INTO urls (url,pass,`key`)...
```

Comment: +1 and gave the code/syntax if someone doesn't know what a backtick is :)

Comment: Thank you. I'll vote this the best answers, fast and understandable :)

Comment: Got to wait 5 minutes before I can :(